# Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size ERROR CODE

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, summary, sumifs

I am using the following code, but am receiving the 'array arguments to sumifs are of different sizes' error code :

```
=SUMIFS(Expenses!I:I,$A$30,Expenses!B:B,B1,Expenses!H:H)
```

Any helpful ideas on how to fix?

```
=SUMIFS(Expenses!I:I,$A$30,Expenses!B:B,B1,Expenses!H:H)
```

Need name column, amount column and quarter period from expense sheet to populate in a cell that falls in a particular row/column combo.

Comment: Should be like this, If I am not wrong: `=SUMIFS(Expenses!I:I,Expenses!B:B,$A$30,Expenses!H:H,B1)` . `SUMIFS()` syntax reads as `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)` read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)**

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIFS` requires the first argument to be the range that you need to sum up, followed by pairs of condition range and criteria. [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en).  In this regard it is different from `SUMIF` that has different order of arguments.

In your case the order should be (if `Expenses!H:H` is the range to sum up):

```cpp
=SUMIFS(Expenses!H:H, Expenses!I:I,$A$30,Expenses!B:B,B1)
```